# Knockout select binding value not getting set

Tags: knockout.js

I have a gird that has some values, when I click edit I am able to see the values in the function being called but when I set the value that I need to be selected it seem not to get set in the dropdown.  One thing I did notice is the value is set like `"1"` but the data returned is just `1`, not sure it that would cause the issue

I am pretty sure this is something simple but not able to see what I am missing.

`objUserList.selectedPartner(data.ProgramID());`

This has the value but the selected option does not get set

My code

```
var objUserList;
vmUserListModel = function () {
  var self = this;
  self.UserList = ko.observableArray([]); // Populate the users
  self.Partners = ko.observableArray([]); // Populate the Partners
  self.selectedPartner = ko.observable();

  self.EditUser = function (index, data) {
     console.log(data.ProgramID()); // here I can see the value but it shows as a number with the ""
     objUserList.GetPartners();  // populate a the dropdown from an ajax call
     objUserList.selectedPartner(data.ProgramID());  // in firebug console again the value is here
     objUserList.selectedRole(data.RoleID());

    }
}
```

**HTML**

The edit icon place that calls the above edit function

```
<div data-bind="event: {click: $root.EditUser.bind($data, $index())}">
                </div>
```

The select binding

```
<select id="Partner" data-bind="options: objUserList.Partners, optionsText: 'ProgramName', optionsValue: 'ProgramID', value: objUserList.selectedPartner, optionsCaption: 'Select'">
                </select>
```

I tried to reproduce using an existing fiddle as found the same issue

http://jsfiddle.net/adriandcosta/h92xfd88/1/

**Working code**

I am filling the dropdown via an ajax call.  So even before the ajax call returned the value, I was trying to set the selected value.  Adding `valueAllowUnset: true` fixed the issue

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the fiddle had nothing to do with your question. It was that `value` binding was added twice with different values, I fixed that and it worked:
http://jsfiddle.net/0j2n2ay3/

About your question, so you're biding your `select` to `self.selectedPartner` but in the function you are updating the value of `objUserList.selectedPartner`? What if you try to set `self.selectedPartner(data.ProgramID());` instead?

Comment: That did not make a difference as the dropdown is being filled by a ajax call.  So even before the value got returned from the ajax call I was trying to set the selected value.  I added ``valueAllowUnset`` and that worked.  I updated my answer with the working code